# How to round in swift?

Tags: swift, variables, math, rounding

I am trying to round the answer to this code to 2 decimal places. I have tried a bunch of methods and none of them work for me. Please help!

```
import Foundation

var yen: Double = 10
var krona: Double = 10
var rupee: Double = 10
var totalMoney: Double

var yenRate = 0.0088
var kronaRate = 0.116
var rupeeRate = 0.013


totalMoney = yenRate*yen + kronaRate*krona + rupeeRate*rupeeRate

print("The total of all currencies is equal to \(totalMoney) in USD.")
```

Answer (score 1):

there many ways to do that

1. if you want the value to assign it to label in string format

   ```
    var yen: Double = 10
    var krona: Double = 10
    var rupee: Double = 10
    var totalMoney: Double
    var yenRate = 0.0088
    var kronaRate = 0.116
    var rupeeRate = 0.013


    totalMoney = yenRate*yen + kronaRate*krona + rupeeRate*rupeeRate

    let doubleStr = String(format: "%.2f", totalMoney)

    print(doubleStr)
   ```

here %.2f round it to 2 decimal points and its a string value

2.you have add this extension in your project

```
extension Double {
func round(to places: Int) -> Double {
    let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
    return (self * divisor).rounded() / divisor
  }
}
```

then use it in ur class like

```
totalMoney = yenRate*yen + kronaRate*krona + rupeeRate*rupeeRate
let totlaMoneyInDouble = Double(totlaMoney)
```

this will return a double value